# How to create a delete link for a related object in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

So let's say I have Posts and Comments and the url for show is `/posts/1/comments/1`. I want to create a link to delete that comment in the comments controller destroy method. How do I do that?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post_comment_path(@post, comment),
            data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, :method => :delete %>
```

in comments controller:

```
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to post_comments_path(@post) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

Comment: You also have to be sure that you have a <%= javascript_include_tag :all %> or similar tag in your header. Otherwise the link will be there but will not respect the :method => :delete. Just adding this comment because that was stumping me just now....

Comment: Quick note: `javascript_include_tag :all` is depricated in Rails > 3.1, the application layout defaults with `= javascript_include_tag "application"` which will accomplish the same thing

Comment: I ran into an issue where my AJAX links were logging users out. I ended up having to include the CSRF tags in the layout. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434283/rails-3-ajax-delete-links-log-out-current-user#comment7719982_6507424 It's not entirely related to this actual question, but some people may run into this unexpectedly.

Comment: Updating your answer as per the answer below about "confirm: Are you sure?" to be included in data hash. I tried and verified it. It does need to be in the data hash.

Answer (score 11):

Since some time ago, the `confirm` option has to be included in a `data` hash, otherwise it will be silently ignored:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy',  post_comment_path(@post, comment),
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 5):

Given you have `@post` variable with your post object

#### Before Rails 7

```
<%= link_to 'Delete comment', post_comment_path(@post, comment),
  method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

#### Rails 7 (with Turbo, out of the box)

```
<%= link_to 'Delete comment', post_comment_path(@post, comment),
  data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you have `<span>`, `<i>` or nested elements inside of a `<a>` tag this way link_to use is difficult. You can inseted use raw HTML which is easy to handle, like so:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm" href="/blogs/<%=@blog.id%>" data-method="delete">             
  <i class="pg-trash"></i><span class="bold">Delete</span>
</a>
```

Comment: You can still use **link_to** in these cases by passing a block to define the link name:

    <%= link_to @blog, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-sm" do %>
    <i class="pg-trash"></i><span class="bold">Delete</span>
    <% end %>

Answer (score 1):

## In rails 7.0.4.2

### You can use destroy method this way 'turbo gem'

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', user, data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

**Turbo** gives you the speed of a single-page web application without having to write any **JavaScript**. **Turbo** accelerates links and form submissions without requiring you to change your server-side generated **HTML**. It lets you carve up a page into independent frames, which can be lazy-loaded and operate as independent components. And finally, helps you make partial page updates using just **HTML** and a set of **CRUD-like** container tags. These three techniques reduce the amount of custom **JavaScript** that many web applications need to write by an order of magnitude. You can install '**turbo**' in terminal by:

```
gem install turbo-rails -v 1.0.1
```

Or in Gemfile and bundled it.

```
gem 'turbo-rails', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'
```

Then

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Hopefully this comment get's upvoted to the top since this is the most up to date answer as of now.