# No route matches [GET], for delete request

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am getting routing error `No route matches [GET]` upon `delete` request. Here is my delete route 
`delete '/remove/:product_id', to: 'carts#remove_product'` 
I am using it like this 
`<a href="/remove/<%=subq.product.id%>" method="delete"></a>`. Any idea about this error?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the `link_to` helper? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317448/how-to-create-a-delete-link-for-a-related-object-in-ruby-on-rails) may be what you are trying to do.

Comment: Noting special. Just using a-tag because of styling reasons, because I have an i-tag inside my a-tag. It should not make any difference. right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Justin Wood suggested, you could use Rails' link_to helper, which would look like this :

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', your_method_path(subq.product), :method => :delete %>
```

If you want to stick to your current way of doing it, you could try (please note `data-method` instead of `method`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35283202/4480140):

```
<a href="/remove/<%=subq.product.id%>" data-method="delete"></a>
```

And also check that in your application.js file you have

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

And finally that application.js file is included into `view/layout/application.html.erb` file. Cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/17748391/4480140

Comment: Thank-you! Worked perfectly by only replacing method with data-method.